# Watir-webdriver: how to change attribute value without js/jquery

Tags: watir-webdriver

How can I change a href attribute value using watir-webdriver without using js/jquery?

I can get an attribute value:

```
@browser.frames[2].div(:id,"mid-2").link(:class,"btn-lrg").attribute_value("href")
```

But I also need to change a bit of the href attribute value.

Comment: Why do you need to do it without js/jquery? I can understand without jquery since it might not be available. However, javascript should be available.

Comment: How would you do that manually?

Comment: Manually I go to html code of the page and change the href value and then click the link...

Comment: @AnnaVoit, any comment on why injecting javascript is not acceptable?

Comment: I simply try to avoid js using just page-object methods since it's easy to modify code in case html code is changed. so now to get href i use: 
  in_frame(:index => 2) do |frame|
    h2(:congrats,:css => "div.content h2", :frame => frame)
  end
  ...
   new_href = href_plus_element.when_present.attribute("href").gsub("//my","//qa")
        @browser.goto  new_href; but I don't wanna use goto... I wanna change the link and click it as a normal user  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the only way to modify the link is to use javascript. The code is quite maintainable since the element is retrieved using watir.

```rb
#Get the first link (or any element you want)
element = browser.frame.link

#Check element's initial attribute
puts element.attribute_value('href')
#=> "page_a.html"

#Execute javascript to change the attribute
script = "return arguments[0].href = 'page_b.html'"
browser.execute_script(script, element)

#Check that the attribute has changed
puts element.attribute_value('href')
#=> "page_b.html"
```