# Click on deeply nested div in Watir

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to click on checkbox (which represents as ) in Firefox using Watir. I have code left to me from the previous tester, and this code works in Chrome, but not Firefox.

Here is what I have.

Here is the code that leads to this div:

```
<div class="x-grid3-body" style="width:515px;" id="ext-gen201">
    <div class="x-grid3-row  x-grid3-row-first" style="width:515px;">
        <table class="x-grid3-row-table" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:515px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-0 x-grid3-cell-first " style="width: 158px;" tabindex="0">
                        <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">Organisation</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-1 " style="width: 298px;" tabindex="0">
                        <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-1 x-unselectable" unselectable="on">Catch Software</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-scopeCheckColumn x-grid3-cell-last  x-grid3-check-col-td" style="width: 53px;" tabindex="0">
                        <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-scopeCheckColumn x-unselectable" unselectable="on">
                            <div class="x-grid3-check-col x-grid3-cc-scopeCheckColumn">&nbsp;</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need essentially is to click on this div

```
<div class="x-grid3-check-col x-grid3-cc-scopeCheckColumn">&nbsp;</div>
```

I can't attach screenshots (rating is low), but this div is the checkbox that I need to click.

This piece of code works in Chrome:

```
@browser.div(:class => 'x-box-inner', :index => 1).table(:class => 'x-grid3-row-table').td(:text => 'Organisation').parent.td(:index => 2)
```

But in Firefox I can see that Watir is just click on the whole parent div (can see selection appear in browser), not on the checkbox div.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there is only one element in the html you've showed that has the class 'x-grid3-cc-scopeCheckColumn', so is there a reason you can't do:

`@browser.td(class: 'x-grid3-cc-scopeCheckColumn').click`

If not, you can simplify your element location drastically to get the td you want, since there is only one td that has the text 'Organisation', and .parent would only get the td above it, but it looks like you want the tr tag above that, so perhaps you want:

`@browser.td(text: 'Organisation').parent.parent.td(index: 2)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, there are many 'x-grid3-cc-scopeCheckColumn' as I have many rows with checkboxes. The second solution worked, but again — only in Chrome. In Firefox it does nothing in the browser. Though it CMD it looks like it clicks on the element, as it clearly finds it.

Comment: Is Firefox throwing an error, or is the checkbox just not clicked?
Also, if your code has a div instead of an input/checkbox, I suspect there is likely javascript things involved which can complicate things.

Comment: Yes, probably, there are some JS that is blocking. I opened selenium in Firefox, and other actions (like when I click on buttons) are recorded, but this checkbox doesn't record anything in Selenium. I will ask dev to figure this out.

Comment: I think I understand how it works. JS is changing the class of div. It appends "-on", and the checkbox becomes clicked (was: x-grid3-check-col, becomes: x-grid3-check-col-on). Is it possible not to replace the whole class of div using Watir, but just append, as I have multiple classes in my div. I have tried this method (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703979/watir-webdriver-how-to-change-attribute-value-without-js-jquery), but no changes noticed in Firefox

Comment: You might try the fire_event method, which simulates JavaScript events on element ```browser.td(id: 'foo').fire_event :click```
I've never tried changing the class of a DOM element. Watir is supposed to replicate the user actions as best as possible.
I'm not sure if it makes a difference here, but you might also try disabling Native Events - http://watirmelon.com/2011/09/16/disabling-native-events-when-using-firefox-with-webdriver/

Answer (score 0):

Using an XPath worked for me in Firefox:

```
@browser.div(:xpath, "//*[@id='ext-gen201']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div").click
```

I was able to verify it with `.flash` in place of `.click` since your div just contains a space and there was nothing to otherwise see.

Comment: Thanks! I actually solved it by this code: @browser.td(text: 'Organisation').parent.parent.td(index: 2).div.div(class: 'x-grid3-check-col x-grid3-cc-scopeCheckColumn').click. However, I think I should have tried using xpath... oh well, next something breaks, I guess.